# Bulk loading with LoadIncrementalHFiles and subdirectories

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bulk-load, hfile

I wrote a Spark application that generates HFiles to be used for bulk loading with the `LoadIncrementalHFiles` command later. As the source data pool is very big, the input files are splitted into iterations that are processed one after the other. Each iteration creates its own `HFile` directory, so my HDFS structure looks like this:

```
/user/myuser/map_data/hfiles_0
         ...         /hfiles_1
         ...         /hfiles_2
         ...         /hfiles_3
                     ...
```

There are about 500 files in this `map_data` directory, therefore I'm searching for a way to automatically call the `LoadIncrementalHFiles` function, to process these subdirectories also in iterations later.

The corresponding command would be this:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles -Dcreate.table=no /user/myuser/map_data/hfiles_0 mytable
```

I need to change this into an iterative command, as this command does not work with subdirectories (when I call it with the `/user/myuser/map_data` directory)!

I tried to use a Java `Process` instance to execute the command above automatically, but this doesn't seen to do anything (no output to console and also no more rows in my HBase table).

Using the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles` Java class out of my code also doesn't work, it's also not responsing!

Has anybody a working example for me? Or is there a parameter to be able to run the above `hbase` command on the parent directory? I'm working with HBase 1.1.2 in a Hortonworks Data Platform 2.5 cluster.

**EDIT** I tried to run the `LoadIncrementalHFiles` command from a Hadoop client Java application, but I'm getting an exception relating to snappy compression, see [Run LoadIncrementalHFiles from Java client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405738/run-loadincrementalhfiles-from-java-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to split the `hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles -Dcreate.table=no /user/myuser/map_data/hfiles_0 mytable` command into many parts (one per command part), see this Java code snippet:

```
TreeSet<String> subDirs = getHFileDirectories(new Path(HDFS_PATH), hadoopConf);

for(String hFileDir : subDirs) {

    try {
        String pathToReadFrom = HDFS_OUTPUT_PATH + "/" + hFileDir;
        ==> String[] execCode = {"hbase", "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles", "-Dcreate.table=no", pathToReadFrom, hbaseTableName};
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(execCode);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        final Process p = pb.start();

        // Write the output of the Process to the console
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line = null; 

                try {
                    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                        System.out.println(line);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    // Wait for the end of the execution
    p.waitFor();
    ...
}
```