# Run LoadIncrementalHFiles from Java client

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop2, snappy, hfile

I want to call `hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles /user/myuser/map_data/hfiles mytable` method from my Java client code.

When I run the application I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.CorruptHFileException: Problem reading HFile Trailer from file webhdfs://myserver.de:50070/user/myuser/map_data/hfiles/b/b22db8e263b74a7dbd8e36f9ccf16508
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.pickReaderVersion(HFile.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.createReader(HFile.java:520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.groupOrSplit(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$3.call(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:549)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$3.call(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:546)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support.
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getDecompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getDecompressor(CodecPool.java:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.compress.Compression$Algorithm.getDecompressor(Compression.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.compress.Compression.decompress(Compression.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.encoding.HFileBlockDefaultDecodingContext.prepareDecoding(HFileBlockDefaultDecodingContext.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock.unpack(HFileBlock.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$AbstractFSReader$1.nextBlock(HFileBlock.java:1350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$AbstractFSReader$1.nextBlockWithBlockType(HFileBlock.java:1356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2.<init>(HFileReaderV2.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV3.<init>(HFileReaderV3.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.pickReaderVersion(HFile.java:467)
    ... 8 more
```

Running the `hbase ...` command above from console on my Hadoop server works perfectly. But when I try to run these from my Java Code using HBase /Hadoop client libraries it fails with the exception!

Here a code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Configuration conf = loginFromKeyTab("REALM.DE", "server.de", "user", "C:/user.keytab");
        conf.set("fs.webhdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.class.getName());
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "server1.de,server2.de,server3.de");
        conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-secure");
        conf.set("hbase.master.kerberos.principal", "hbase/_HOST@REALM.DE");
        conf.set("hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal", "hbase/_HOST@REALM.DE");
        conf.set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos");

        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
        Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("mytable"));

        RegionLocator locator = connection.getRegionLocator(table.getName());

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Test Bulk Load"); 

        //HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table, locator);     
        //Configuration conf2 = job.getConfiguration();

        LoadIncrementalHFiles loader = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(conf);
        loader.doBulkLoad(new Path(HDFS_PATH), connection.getAdmin(), table, locator);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Do I need to add a dependency to my project? But how / where / which version?

I'm working with HDP 2.5 which contains HBase 1.1.2 and Hadoop 2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution for my issue: I'm using a Java program that runs a `Process` instance that calls the `LoadIncrementalHFiles` method automatically (running directly on the Hadoop node), instead of using the `LoadIncrementalHFiles` class itself in my code!

Here the code snippet of my solution:

```
TreeSet<String> subDirs = getHFileDirectories(new Path(HDFS_OUTPUT_PATH), conf);        // The HDFS_OUTPUT_PATH directory contains many HFile sub-directories

for(String hFileDir : subDirs) {
    String pathToReadFrom = HDFS_OUTPUT_PATH + "/" + hFileDir;

    String[] execCode = {"hbase", "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles", "-Dcreate.table=no", pathToReadFrom, "mytable"};       // Important: Separate each parameter here!!!
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(execCode);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    final Process p = pb.start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null; 

            try {
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
    }).start();

    p.waitFor();

    int exitCode = p.exitValue();
    System.out.println(" ==> Exit Code: " + exitCode);
}

System.out.println("Finished");
```

If somebody has another solution (e.g. how to use the `LoadIncrementalHFiles` class directly in code), let me know. Thank you!